Timing of events in responses of trees to pruning
Original Post
I recently pruned a shrub of all of its leafy branches.  A week or so later it started sending out new branches.  I am making the assumption that those branches would not have grown where they did if I had not pruned the shrub.  This observation made me wonder how quickly does a plant notice the loss of a limb and begin to grow new limbs?  More generally, how quickly does information about one part of a plant propagate/diffuse/transport to other parts of the plant, and what is(are) the mechanism(s) of that information transfer?  Unless the information transport mechanism and speed can vary wildly from species to species, I can't imagine the speed is very fast, as some boughs that I lopped off of a different tree started to have new growth a month or so after I cut them off (new spring leaves).
EDIT
From the comment provided (Thank you! It was very helpful!), I have learned that I really did not know what I did not know.  My background is physics and classical mechanics with very limited biology (one college class) and chemistry (high school).  After reading the referenced article I feel like I have a very basic understanding of shoot branching.  I still have a question relevant to my original question, so I will briefly summarize what I understand and then ask my question.
A plant has a dominant tip which generates hormones, such as auxin and possibly others, that stop the growth of other buds along the branch.  Those other buds are always present and are potentially created because of gene mutation during the growth of the branch (this is a guess; the article did not say where these secondary buds come from).  Thus, the "signal" for the other buds to grow from the decapitation is the loss of a source of auxin, and the speed at which this "signal" propagates would be the speed at which the concentration of the relevant inhibiting hormones decreases.
So, here is another, perhaps simple, question: how quickly does the vasculature of a plant exchange chemicals?  From this paper it looks like it is either on the order of hours (from bud growth plots) to minutes (from sugar counts).
To be honest, there is a lot about this topic that fascinates and confuses me, but I know that this post is not the place for an extended series of questions, so I will leave it at the one question above.

Hi and welcome. Maybe a bit more detail would help you get an answer. What do you know about plant vasculature and apical dominance? You're asking about auxin transport. This site strongly recommends evidence of prior research attempting to answer your question (e.g. a quote and a link) (so we know what you know.)

We try to avoid unjustified anthropomorphic expressions in biology, which is why I have edited your title to remove the word "notice". The replacement tries to reflect the rephrasing of the question in your edit.
